# C++ cannot open source file "opencv2/tracking.hpp"

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, include, opencv-contrib

I am trying to use OpenCV multi-tracker, but it doesn't find `tracking.hpp`. I have built OpenCV with **OpenCV-contrib** modules based on [these instructions](https://cv-tricks.com/how-to/installation-of-opencv-4-1-0-in-windows-10-from-source/). Now in Visual Studio, I have done this:

[image]

where `$OPENCV_DIR` is a user variable:

[image]

I also have;

- added the path `C:\opencv\opencv4.2.0\opencv-4.2.0\build\install\x64\vc16\lib` to the `Linker -> Gnereal -> Additional Library Directories`.
- added `opencv_world420.lib` to `Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies`

Now the problem is that `opencv.hpp` and `tracking.hpp` aren't detected:

[image]

Both `opencv.hpp` and `tracking.hpp` exist in `C:\opencv\opencv4.2.0\opencv-4.2.0\build\install\include\opencv2`. What should I do to make the program recognize **OpenCV-contrib** modules?

Comment: Not sure here, but what happens if you take out the `opencv2/` from the header names in the source files? Look like you already have that directory as part of the "Additional include directories."

Comment: Did you try to compile ? Because the error in the last picture you showed is just about the editor settings, not about the compiler settings. If it compiles, then your files are properly found, and it is just the intelliSense or something like that which is misconfigured.

Comment: Joining @AdrianMole, but I'd rather remove the opencv2 subpath in one of the additional include paths and drop the other one entirely...

Comment: @Aconcagua I would agree that's probably the better approach. Just thought that editing the cpp file would be a quicker "test" to see if that's actually the problem.

Comment: @Aconcagua See answer - hope it's not too garbled!

Comment: Yes that was the problem. I added `C:\opencv\opencv4.2.0\opencv-4.2.0\build\install\include` to **Additional include directories** and the errors went away.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*<sup>**Note:** This answer has been formed largely by combining and expanding on comments made by myself and others:</sup>*

The problem is a 'conflict' between your specified "Additional Include Directories" and the specified name of the header(s) in your `#include` lines, in that you have specified the folder, "opencv2" **twice**.

For example, the line:

```cpp
#include <opencv2/tracking.hpp>
```

Looks for the file `tracking.hpp` in a **sub-directory** called `opencv2` in each of the defined search paths. In your case, this is looking for:

> OPENCV_DIR\include\opencv2\opencv2\tracking.hpp

… and that file (in fact, the folder) doesn't exist.

So, just specify this as your (single) "Additional Include Directory:"

> OPENCV_DIR\include

… then, when the compiler 'constructs' the path for the header, it will append `/opencv2/tracking.hpp` to (each of) the specified search directories, and will be able to find: `OPENCV_DIR\include` + `/` + `opencv2/tracking.hpp`, as this will evaluate to:

> OPENCV_DIR\include\opencv2\tracking.hpp

Comment: Thank you! Adding `OPENCV_DIR\include` to **Additional include directories** solved the problem.

Comment: Always happy to help! Note that, so long as you *consistently* use the `<opencv2/file2.hpp>` and/or `<ppencv/file.hpp>` format in your `#include` lines, then you don't need those specific directories in your Additional Includes list.